# Django Haystack. How to exclude by PK (does not work).

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I have search queryset and want exclude some PKs.
How to exclude from resut some results by PK.

```
 #SearchQuerySet
.filter(~SQ(pk=777))
.filter(~SQ(pk__in=777))
.exclude(pk__in=777)
.exclude(pk=777)
```

None of that does not works.

Comment: Do you need this filter in all queries or in some of them?

Comment: Also, please note `__in` works with arrays i.e. `.exclude(pk__in=[777,])`